# How can I avoid capital letter in the authors' names using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing, iso

I am using **biblatex** for citation and its style is **iso-authoryear**.

My problem is that the used style makes the names of the authors capital which I do not want except from the first letter of name and surname.

How can I succeed that?

My code in **document.tex**:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{sources.bib} 

\begin{document}

The IoT environment are.... \cite{IoT Book}.

\end{document}
```

My code in **sources.tex**:

```
@Article{IoT Book,
  author  = {Kaks Johny},
  title   = {dkjakja},
  journal = {adaad},
  year    = {2003}
}
```

**Result**:

> KAKS JOHNY, bla bla bla

**What I want**:

> Kaks Johny, bla bla bla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex-iso` defines the macro `\lastnameformat` to control the formatting of (family/last) names in the bibliography. See https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/blob/8e55c1bdb6ce2e2eab23f9fd98b096cfaff0d9b1/iso.bbx#L95-L100. We can redefine that macro to do nothing, which results in the desired output.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\lastnameformat}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Sigfridsson et al., 1998" in citations, "Sigfridsson, Emma; Ryde, Ulf, 1998." in the bibliography.]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use.

```
\usepackage{apacite}
```

in your preamble. Then print it APA style.

```
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: APA style is quite different from ISO authoryear style as implemented by `biblatex-iso` (based on Czech and Slovakian translation of ISO 690). Plus `apacite` is completely incompatible with `biblatex` and thus requires a different workflow.